# How to write a subscript and superscript in Matlab that will be displayed in Graphical User Interface(GUI)?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, subscript, superscript

I want to have a subscript and superscript in my GUI in Matlab. So far I have tried to use x_2 and x^2 and neither of them work. Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158410#398940

> You can use an undocumented feature of all Matlab uicontrols, which is
>   the fact that they use underlying Java Swing controls, and these in
>   turn accept any valid HTML strings. So you can do the following for
>   example:
>
> `uicontrol('string','<html><b>1<sub>2</sub>3<sup>4</sup>5</b></html>')`
>
> This is equivalent to the tex string `'\bf1_23^45\rm'`. You can set font
>   faces, colors, sizes, bold/italic and any other valid HTML 3.0
>   property. It's limited, but should do the trick in most conceivable
>   cases.
>
> The same is true for tooltips, by the way: try setting multi-line
>   (`<br>`) multi-colored (`<font color="red"> ... </font>`) tooltip once and
>   you'll never use the standard boring single-line black tooltip
>   again...
>
> And just in case you were wondering - yes, it also works for menus,
>   listboxes etc.

Comment: Great tip. This will come in handy!

Comment: Thank you Smash! I will try this and let you know.